# Save data with key as npz

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix `A` and I need to save it as a `npz` file, labeled with the `height` key. How can I do that?

To save a random matrix as `npz` I'm using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
Test_matrix = np.random.rand(10,10)
np.savez('Matrix.npz', Test_matrix)
```

But if I load the file and look for `height`, nothing is found:

```
M = np.load('Matrix.npz')
MM = M['height'].reshape(512,512)
```

Gives the error `'height is not a file in the archive'`

Comment: You never reference `height` in the `Test_matrix` when you save it. It's just an array when you save it. The default key when no dict is provided is "arr_0".

Comment: What does 'height' have to do with `Test_matrix`?

Comment: @hpaulj `height` is used as a keyword in another script which is a bit tricky to change.

Comment: @JayMody What is the best way to change the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments say, you never tell `savez` that you want to call it "height". You can save with keys by passing them as `**kwds`. Make sure to [check the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) for any given function if you're having trouble with it.

Also you can't reshape a `(10,10)` to `(512,512)` so I've fixed that here:

```
import numpy as np
Test_matrix = np.random.rand(512,512)
np.savez('Matrix.npz', height=Test_matrix)
M = np.load('Matrix.npz')
MM = M['height'].reshape(512,512)
print(MM.shape)
(512, 512)
```

**Edit**: To clarify based on your comment, the keyword you pass to `savez` doesn't have to match the name of the object. The way I did it above should work for you.